# MS Access count(*) query in Ruby script not returning with a number

Tags: sql, ruby, ms-access, count, adodb

I have a script I want to determine the number of records in a Microsoft Access database table and assign that to a variable.  I have the code below (snippet) which runs without error but the result is not a number but instead #.  Is this a number in some other format?  Can I convert it into a number?  When I run the SQL in Access, I get 43 (for example); that's what I was expecting.

...

```
connection = WIN32OLE.new('ADODB.Connection')
connection.Open('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                 Data Source=C:\Database.mdb')
recordset = WIN32OLE.new('ADODB.Recordset')
  number_of_sites =  connection.Execute("SELECT count(*)FROM Test;")
  puts number_of_sites
```

...

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connection.Execute doesn't return data, it just executes the sql. You might use it to do an INSERT. To fetch data, you need a recordset.

```
recordset = WIN32OLE.new('ADODB.Recordset')
recordset.Open("SELECT count(*) FROM Test", connection)
count = recordset[0]
```

I'm not positive about the index on recordset- it might be recordset[1]?

Comment: That works but it doesn't like 0 or 1 in the last line.  It returns an error saying '[]': can't convert Fixnum into String (Type Error).  I got around it by doing this     data=recordset.GetRows
puts data

Answer (score 1):

Andrew is close - connection.Execute returns a recordset, not a scalar.  To get the count, you want 'recordset.Fields(0).value).